# ABPeoplePickerView is leaving hidden windows? (OSX)

Tags: macos, cocoa, abaddressbook, abpeoplepickerview

This is how I discovered the problem:

My app has a small dialog window with an ABPeoplePickerView. This window (or its controller) is correctly deallocated when finished with.

When the app terminates, in `applicationShouldTerminate:` I iterate through all its windows (`[NSApp windows]`) and if the window has a delegate and it responds to `windowShouldClose:` I call that method and if the response is NO, I stop the termination.

Logging each window's title revealed that each time I created my dialog window, two extra hidden windows were created, with titles: "People Picker Debug Info" and "People Picker Preview", and that these windows aren't disposed of when the dialog is closed. You can actually see these windows if you makeKeyAndOrderFront them. The latter is blank. A long run of the app could create a large number of these windows, presumably using up resources. Should I worry? Should I do anything about it? Could I make use of them?

My hunch is to search for these windows by title in my dialog's `deallocate` method, and close them there. Are there any ARC issues?

Answer (score 0):

The following lines in the window controller's dealloc method have fixed the problem, with no side effects as far as I can tell.

```
  for (NSWindow *w in [NSApp windows]) {
    if ([w.title isEqualToString:@"People Picker Debug Info" ]) {
      [w setReleasedWhenClosed:YES];
      [w close];
    }
  if ([w.title isEqualToString:@"People Picker Preview" ]) {
    [w setReleasedWhenClosed:YES];
    [w close];
  }
}
```